# jQuery loop through json?

Tags: jquery, json, each

I have some json (`var data`)that looks like this:

```
{"success":"true","keywords":["firstkeyword","secondkeyword"]}
```

And im trying to loop through the keywords using this code:

```
            data.keywords.each(function(e){
                $('#campaign_keywords').append("<p>"+e+"</p>");
            });
```

But i get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object firstkeyword,secondkeyword has no method 'each'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to loop through it like this:

```
$.each(data.keywords, function (i, v) {
    $('#campaign_keywords').append("<p>"+data.keywords[i]+"</p>");
});
```

[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: Just use `v` to access the values.

Answer (score 3):

That's because it's an array and it needs to be a jquery wrapped object in order to use jquery functions.  Try:

```
$.each(data.keywords, function(index, value){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a javascript array, not jQuery object. just apply $ over it to make it jquery object like

```
    $(data.keywords).each(function(e){
        $('#campaign_keywords').append("<p>"+e+"</p>");
    });
```